# Circle Profile Image on Sliver Appbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to include a circle profile image button on my sliver app bar but the sliver app bar isn't quite rendering it right. This is what i'm getting, how can I achieve a circle profile image on a sliver app bar?

[image]

My Code:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Home'),
              leading: Container(),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                    onPressed: () {}),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/images/blank_profile.png'))
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => ProfilePage())),
                  ),
                ),
              ],

            ),
```

Using a CircleAvatar :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Home'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              leading: Container(),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                    onPressed: () {}),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/blank_profile.png'),
                  minRadius: 28,
                ),
              ],

            ),
```

[image]

Comment: Use circle Avatar widget https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html

Comment: Still isn't rendering it right

Comment: A circle image you would find on an app bar in any modern day app I'm sure you've encountered apps where the user profile image appears as a circular image on the app bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that you have to use [CircleAvatar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) for that.

This is the code you can use:

```
SliverAppBar(
  title: Text('Home'),
  leading: Container(),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
      onPressed: () {}),
    CircleAvatar(
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/blank_profile.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: It is still not rendering it right, i updated my question with the results i'm getting

Comment: Did you exactly tried my code? Because in updated question you added `minRadius: 28` in CircleAvatar which makes it bit bigger then required. And if that's not the problem then what do you mean by not rendering it right?

Comment: Yeah your code renders it as a square image so I added the radius

Comment: Try adding a circle avatar to a flutter sliver app bar is coming out as a square for some reason

Comment: Their seem to be issue with CircleAvatar backgroundImage property so i updated the answer with ClipOval as a child and it works perfert now.